# What do "졌다고" and "없기다" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

> 남자 : 누나, 뭐 해? 심심한데 나가서 배드민턴 치자
>
> 여자 : 좋아. 그런데 지난번처럼 졌다고 화내기 없기다.

The sentence is difficult for me to understand because of "졌다고" and "없기다". i think 졌다고 = 졌다고해서, but as i know, "다고 하다" means "someone say that (i heard that)" so i think it is not correct  in this sentence, and i never saw "없기다" in Korean grammar structure . Help me to understand it. Thank!

Answer (score 3):

Good afternoon,

The sentences can be translated as below:

> Man: Sister, what are you doing? I'm bored. Let's get out and play badminton.
>
> Woman: Fine. But you should not be upset like last time even if you lose.

Here "졌다고" should be translated as "even if you lose", and "없기다" as "there should not be such a thing that".

**Added:**

Some example sentences.

> "배부르다고 음식 남기기 없기다."
>   (Even if you get full, you should not make any leftover.)
>
> "영화가 재미없다고 중간에 영화관에서 나가기 없기다."
>   (Even if the movie is found to be boring, you should not go out from the theater while the movie is still playing.)

Comment: thank you. Can you explain more detail, so i can use these grammar structure in other situation? Thank!

Comment: Hi, I added several example sentenced to my answer. I hope they will be useful.

Comment: thank you. In these example, "다고" = "아/어 도", and they can be interchangeable, right?

Comment: Oh I see your point. Let me say like this: "배부르다고" -> "배불러도" is fine, and "영화가 재미없다고" -> "영화가 재미없어도" is also fine. If this is what you meant by "다고" = "아/어 도", then that's correct.